# "npm install" does not intall anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Currently I've started learning VueJs, and i can't pass through anything related to "npm".I cannot install anything on "npm".

> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
>
> npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli failed,
> reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
>
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad
> network settings. npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help
> config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\FUJITSU\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-16T03_59_16_611Z-debug.log

---

**Below my log file.**

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'install',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '-g',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'vue-cli'
>
> 1 verbose cli ]
>
> 2 info using npm@6.14.4
>
> 3 info using node@v12.17.0
>
> 4 verbose npm-session 513508fbe2b1aac6
>
> 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
>
> 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
>
> 7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-cli@latest request to
> http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli
>
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
>
> 8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
>
> 9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 310ms
>
> 10 verbose type system
>
> 11 verbose stack FetchError: request to
> http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli failed, reason: getaddrinfo
>
> ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
>
> 11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest. (C:\Program
>
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener
> (_http_client.js:426:9)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
>
> 11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
>
> 12 verbose cwd C:\Vue.Js
>
> 13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
>
> 14 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
> "vue-cli"
>
> 15 verbose node v12.17.0
>
> 16 verbose npm  v6.14.4
>
> 17 error code ENOTFOUND
>
> 18 error errno ENOTFOUND
>
> 19 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli failed,
> reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND  proxy.company.com
>
> 20 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> 20 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad
> network settings.
>
> 20 error network
>
> 20 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> 20 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help
> config'
>
> 21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: what command did you typed in?

Comment: npm isntall vue-cli

Comment: did you tried `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: yes,still is not working.

Comment: Indeed i am failing to set proxy conf

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command first.

```
npm config delete proxy
```